# Can't deploy flink application

Tags: apache-flink

I am using Hortonworks 2.4.0.

I am starting the yarn-session with ./bin/yarn-session.sh -n 1 -jm 768 -tm 768

Then, I want to deploy ./bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 1 -yjm 768 -ytm 768 ./examples/batch/WordCount.jar

When I deploy my application, I run into an endless loop. The logging message is: INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.FlinkYarnClient                         - Deployment took more than 60 seconds. Please check if the requested resources are available in the YARN cluster

I already adjusted the parameters for n 1 -jm 768 -tm to various values. Including to those as recommended in: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/setup/yarn_setup.html
 It did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `./bin/yarn-session.sh -n 1 -jm 768 -tm 768` command, you are starting a long running YARN session.

You can then submit a job to the session using the ./bin/flink client (without passing the -m yarn-cluster argument)

If you want to submit a single job to YARN using Flink, `./bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 1 -yjm 768 -ytm 768` is the right approach for submitting the job.